# apt-get upgrade got aborted how to recover? (hash sum mismatch)

Tags: debian, apt

I asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963098/apt-get-upgrade-got-aborted-how-to-recover) but was redirected here .

I'm afraid I made a kind of a booboo.

While performing an `apt-get upgrade` (there were about 160+ packages in queue) I accidentally logged out, thus aborting the upgrade midway. Now I can't restart the upgrade.

`apt-get upgrade` says there are no packages to upgrade...

`apt-get update` gives errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/contrib/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/non-free/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

[several more of these... and ending in: ]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache
```

Full output is [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UNAP4xm5)

I tried these without success:

- `apt-get -f install`

*Output:*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

- `dpkg --configure -a`

*No output*

- `rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*; apt-get update`

*Same errors as above.*

- `dpkg-reconfigure -a`

*Eventually aborts after this:*

```
[ ok ] Stopping acpid (via systemctl): acpid.service.
[ ok ] Starting acpid (via systemctl): acpid.service.
[ ok ] Stopping apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
[ ok ] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.
gpg: key B98321F9: "Squeeze Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 473041FA: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 65FFB764: "Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 46925553: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 518E17E1: "Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 2B90D010: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key C857C906: "Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 7
gpg:              unchanged: 7
[ ok ] Stopping avahi-daemon (via systemctl): avahi-daemon.service.
[ ok ] Reloading dbus configuration (via systemctl): dbus.service.
[ ok ] Starting avahi-daemon (via systemctl): avahi-daemon.service.
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man7/builtins.7.gz (builtins.7.gz) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
[ ok ] Starting loadcpufreq (via systemctl): loadcpufreq.service.
[ ok ] Starting cpufrequtils (via systemctl): cpufrequtils.service.
[ ok ] Stopping cron (via systemctl): cron.service.
[ ok ] Starting cron (via systemctl): cron.service.
[ ok ] Starting dbus (via systemctl): dbus.service.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Regenerating fonts cache... done.
udev active, skipping device node creation.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
dpkg-query: error: --status needs a valid package name but 'gcc-4.7-base' is not: ambiguous package name 'gcc-4.7-base' with more than one installed instance

Use --help for help about querying packages.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gcc-4.7-base is not installed
```

I don't know how to find out what was installed and what was not.

Any tips how to recover from this are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably should be moved to superuser or such, but since you already were re-directed...

First I would suggest to run such things in a **screen** session. That will keep the update going when you log out or the connection dies:

```
screen -S upd
```

To de-tach the session press **CTRL a** then press **d**

To re-attach the session type:

```
screen -r upd
```

It will be helpful to also paste the output of the things you listed which you tried without success.

Some suggestions:

- did you try to **switch the repository**
- did you **recursively remove** /var/lib/apt/lists/*
- did you **mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial**

I got my suggestions from: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/

**Edit**: judging from the info you added you may need to force remove **gcc-4.7-base** and then re-install it and repeat **dpkg-reconfigure -a**. If it then fails for another package repeat this process until it succeeds, then re-run apt-get (dist-)upgrade.

Comment: I switched from `us` to `nl` repository. Problem remains.

Comment: I did `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists; mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`. Problem remains.

Comment: See my edited answer.